# Lotus Domino and creating encrypted strings and decript by PHP

Tags: encryption, lotus-domino

Is there any way to create in Lotus Domino an encrypted string which will be used as a variable in a URL then decrypted it on a PHP site? I'm not familiar with Lotus Domino if can be used something like openssl_encrypt or one of the method similar to PHP mcrytp and a "salt" key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lotus Domino supports programming in Java. If there is Java code that you can use to do encryption that is compatible with your PHP, then the answer will be yes. That will depend on the details of what you can do in PHP, and I'm not familiar with that enough to know for sure, but this [question and answser here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10451068/encryption-mismatch-between-java-and-php) strongly suggests to me that the answer is yes -- as long as you get all the little details of encryption modes, padding, encoding, etc. right.